# jQuery slideToggle not firing

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

So I am trying to create a dropdown menu with jquery and have a div (the dropdown) with `display: none`. I am trying to fire the jquery toggle when an `li` item in the above nav bar is clicked. If anyone could take a look at this code and see if there are any obvious errors, that would be great.

Thanks

PS The php code is present as I am working with WP

```
<ul class="right-nav">
    <li style="padding-left: 10px; cursor: pointer;" id="current-user">
    <?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); echo $current_user->user_login; ?>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The dropdown menu:

```
<div class="dropdown-wrapper">
    <div id="user-menu" class="user-menu">
       <ul>
           <li>Hello</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

```
.user-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

And then the jQuery event itself:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#current-user').click(function() {
                $('#user-menu').slideToggle("fast");
        });
    });
```

Comment: What's the rendered HTML of the `.right-nav`?

Comment: It is just within a div. I would send a link but the site is password protected.

Comment: No no, just put it here. What's inside that `li`.

Comment: Man, check my answer. Try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Is "user-menu" inside of "current-user", and it is a unique id?

Comment: @dwinnbrown Check my answer and explanation. Hope it works.

Comment: @mottie no it's outside and yes its unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man... I guess I kinda got it. Remove the CSS:

```
.user-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

And instead, in teh `document`'s `ready`, give this:

```
$(".user-menu").hide();
```

Trust me, this makes a difference. The reason is, the jQuery first checks if the `style="display: none;"` is there or not in the element, as it is not there, because it is given by the CSS, it gives another `display: none` inline style. This doesn't make any difference. But third time click will reveal it. Give it a try.

Comment: OK will try in a minute

Comment: Doesn't work. I think I might be adding the jquery to Wordpress incorrectly.

Comment: No errors. But I can't think what else it might be?

Comment: @dwinnbrown Any live demo?